# Tensorflow max-margin loss training?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I want to train a neural network in tensorflow with a max-margin loss function using one negative sample per positive sample:

> ```
> max(0,1 -pos_score +neg_score)
> ```

What I'm currently doing is this:
The network takes three inputs: *input1*, and then one positive example *input2_pos* and one negative example *input2_neg*. (These are indices to a word embeddings layer.) The network is supposed to calculate a score that expresses how related two examples are.
Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
input1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
input2_pos = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
input2_neg = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])

# f is a neural network outputting a score
pos_score = f(input1,input2_pos)
neg_score = f(input1,input2_neg)

cost = tf.maximum(0., 1. -pos_score +neg_score)
optimizer= tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

What I see when I run this, is that like this the network just learns which input holds the positive example - it always predicts a similar score along the lines of:

```
pos_score = 0.9965983
neg_score = 0.00341663
```

**How can I structure the variables/training so that the network learns the task instead?**

I want just one network that takes two inputs and calculates a score expressing the correlation between them, and train it with max-margin loss.

Calculating scores for positive and negative separately does not seem like an option to me, since then it won't backpropagate properly. Another option seems to be randomizing inputs - but then for the loss function I need to know which example is the positive one - inputting that as another parameter would give away the solution again?

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code seems fine. If the network predicts 1. for positive pairs and 0. for negative ones it seems to have learned your task perfectly ! Is the loss converging towards 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your results (1 for every positive, 0 for every negative) it seems you have two different networks learning:

- to predict 1 for the first one
- to predict 0 for the second one

When using max-margin loss, you need to use the same network for computing both `pos_score` and `neg_score`. The way to do that is to **share the variables**. I will give you a small example using `tf.get_variable()`:

```
with tf.variable_scope("network"):
    w = tf.get_variable("weights", shape=..., initializer=...)

def f(x, y):
    with tf.variable_scope("network", reuse=True):
        w = tf.get_variable("weights")
        res = w * (x - y)  # some computation
    return res
```

---

With this function `f` as model, the training will optimize the shared variable with name "network/weights".

Comment: Thank you very much!! That seems to have solved the issue :)